# jQueryMobile > DateBox > Using for both Date & TIme

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I want to use jQUeryMobile's DateBox to pick both date and time.
Is it possible to use simple calendar mode ( http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/mode/calbox.html ) with two additional text fields for Hours & minutes?

Because default implementation to scroll for all minutes to pick time, is not very user friendly.

Thanks for suggestions in advance.

Comment: how about some example code as to what you have tried?

Comment: @Phill, I have implemented this link
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/mode/calbox.html